# "msg": "[Errno 20] Not a directory", "rc": 20}

Tags: ansible

I am facing this issue while uploading lambda function to AWS lambda

can't upload full code due to production

```yaml
- name: upload build to lamda-function      
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}:/usr/local/bin/aws"
  command: >
   aws lambda update-function-code
   --function-name  'test-funct' --region 'us-east-1'
   --zip-file fileb:///home/ansadmin/lambda-build.zip
```

Error:

```
 "msg": "[Errno 20] Not a directory", "rc": 20
```

Directory (`/home/ansadmin`) and zipped (`lambda-build.zip`) file is there to upload but getting above error

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

`export` is not a binary file for execution. It's a built-in shell command. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but to have access to built-in shell commands you need to use `shell` module instead of `command`.

Comment: Thanks George, it helps but now I am getting
 "Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint" as a response from AWS

Comment: That's because there is no valid endpoint.